# Present alert controller in main app window?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my model class i want to show alert when something bad happen (for example, server send an error). However, i dont want to bother with delegate or KVO.

Is there an easy way to show an alert for "main" window, to place a view above others?

Currently i use this code (not work, if placed out of viewController classes):

```
UIAlertController *vc =  [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Произошла ошибка"
                                                                     message:response
                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });
        }];
```

Obviously, classes that don't have a view cant use:

```
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
```

Comment: why you dont want to bother with delegate or KVO.

Comment: @MikeAlter effect would be the same but more work.

Comment: one solution would be put alert showing method to appdelegate and show it from top view controller may help

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban There's not always an easy answer - sometimes "more work" means the right way to do something

Comment: @AshleyMills being a good programmer mean being lazy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per solution of @Ashley Mills You can find top view controller with this method

```
- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController
{
    UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
while (topVC.presentedViewController)
{
    topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
}
if ([topVC isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    return [(UINavigationController *)topVC topViewController];
}
return topVC;
}
```

show you alert in return object of `currentTopViewController` method

Comment: What if you have a UISplitViewController in a container, and the detail viewController has presented a modal (or other complicated cases like that). Would this still hold true?

Comment: @SAHM For that case I didn't test this method  , if you have some improvement in this answer  you are welcome to suggest or EDIT

Answer (score 1):

You need to present the `UIAlertController` from a `UIViewController`. If you want the main view controller, you'll need to do this from your application delegate's window's `rootViewController`.

A nasty way to do this is to refer to `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window.rootViewController`

A better way would be to post a notification from your model method and listen for it in the App Delegate

Ideally though you should be looking at passing back an error from your model method to the calling view controller.

Or perhaps you could pass in your current view controller as a parameter to the model method

Comment: thanks, how to implement it with rootViewController?

Comment: Updated the answer